# Plot 2D Histogram as heat map in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I have 3-d data that I want to plot as the following histogram [image: here].
For each bin I have a text file with two columns such as

```
1.12    0.65
1.41    0.95
1.78    1.04
2.24    2.12
```

etc. The first entry of the first column (in the .txt) gives me the value for the center of the first tile, the second row of the first column gives me the value for the center of the second tile etc.   The second column refers to the value on the color bar. The values in the first column and also the bin sizes are logarithmically spaced. I would like to plot this in matplotlib as close to the above as possible (ignoring the arrows).

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would recommend using `plt.imshow` or `plt.pcolor`.

Comment: You probably want to use `bar` with the `bottom` kwarg + `color` kwarg. http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/bar_stacked.html

Comment: I'm not sure how to use `pcolor` when the data only occupies part of the figure i.e. not a full grid.

Comment: Why there are two rows of `1.41    0.95`?

Comment: That was a mistake so I've fixed that now. First column should be logarithmically spaced now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use PolyCollection:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.collections as mc

x = np.logspace(1, 2, 20)
polys = []
values = []
for xs, xe in zip(x[:-1], x[1:]):
    y = np.logspace(1.0, 2+np.random.rand()+2*np.log10(xs), 30)
    c = -np.log(xs*y)
    yp = np.c_[y[:-1], y[:-1], y[1:], y[1:]]
    xp = np.repeat([[xs, xe, xe, xs]], len(yp), axis=0)
    points = np.dstack((xp, yp))
    polys.append(points)
    values.append(c[:-1])

polys = np.concatenate(polys, 0)
values = np.concatenate(values, 0)

pc = mc.PolyCollection(polys)
pc.set_array(values)
fig, ax = pl.subplots()
ax.add_collection(pc)
ax.set_yscale("log")
ax.set_xscale("log")
ax.autoscale()    
pl.colorbar(mappable=pc)
```

here is the output:

[image]