# Plot Stacked Histogram from numpy.histogram output with Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I need to be able to plot the output of `numpy.histogram` using Matplotlib plotting routines. I have seen solutions that use `pyplot.plot` or `pyplot.bar`. However, I need to be able to make a plot styled as the following:

```
pyplot.hist([x1, x2], nbins, weights=[w1, w2], histtype='stepfilled', stacked=True)
```

where `x1, x2, w1, w2` are arrays. I don't know how to make `plot` or `bar` produce the same behavior as the above call to `hist`.

Here is an example of the type of plot I am trying to produce:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn

# sample data
x1 = randn(1000)
x2 = 0.5*randn(1000) + 2

w1 = np.ones(1000)*0.6
w2 = np.ones(1000)*0.7

nbins = 25

plt.hist([x1, x2], nbins, weights=[w1, w2], histtype='stepfilled', stacked=True)

plt.savefig('test.pdf')
```

[image]

Comment: It's very hard to guess the plot you want from a command that doesn't work.  Can you supply some sample data and the picture that you want to get from this data?

Comment: The command does work, actually.

Comment: You might try matplotlib PolyCollection, as in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837713/plot-2d-histogram-as-heat-map-in-matplotlib/21844880#21844880

Comment: Using a PolyCollection makes it much harder to include a legend does it not?